# VS 2019 compiler issue following use of Quick action feature

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (Enterprise version) with all updates. I added the following line of code:

`private DateTime StartDateForQuestions => new DateTime(2021, 12, 3);`

There was a quick action recommendation I selected which resulted in:

`private DateTime StartDateForCNSTFactualQuestions => new(2021, 12, 3);`

I then did further work on the file and when I compiled it there were no errors in the error list but the following appeared in the output file:

```
 CaseListService.cs(46,66,46,70): error CS1031: Type expected
 CaseListService.cs(46,66,46,70): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
 CaseListService.cs(46,66,46,70): error CS1026: ) expected
 CaseListService.cs(46,66,46,70): error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type
 CaseListService.cs(46,66,46,70): error CS1002: ; expected
 CaseListService.cs(46,66,46,70): error CS1519: Invalid token '2021' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

It's a large file so I didn't immediately spot that the error was coming from the Quick action change; reversing that change fixed the problem.

Question - should I avoid this particular Quick action or is there a way of making it work?

Comment: That looks like it's trying to use target-typed new, which is a C# 9 feature - I wouldn't expect that to be supported on VS2019.

Comment: Thanks - is it best to flag that to the VS team? Or just remember not to use it.

Comment: Might be worth flagging to the VS team if you're sure it's from a completely vanilla VS2019 installation. If you've got CodeRush, R# or something similar installed, it may be that that's suggesting it. You might also want to *try* setting `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in your project file - it may well actually compile at that point after all. (In other words, I may have been overly pessimistic about what VS2019 can support.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks; I've flagged it to the VS team. Maybe I'll hear something!